# chartjs V3 align legend text

Tags: chart.js

how to align the legend text to center this is what I have now:

[image]

as you can see the text is not vertically align to center and I dont find any way to do that

this is my options

```
 options.plugins.legend= {
      position: "top",
      align: "start",
      labels: {
        boxWidth: 14,
        boxHeight: 14,
        color: "black",
        usePointStyle: true,
        radius: 55,
        textAlign: "center",
        font: {
          size: 11,
          family: "Roboto",
        },
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution that is to change the svgs code
from

```
 <svg width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14"...
```

to

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16"...
```

and now text aligned